# unknown colors using fcol (pst-solides3d)

Tags: color, pstricks

I am using the pst-solides3d package to draw polytopes in the following way:

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-0.5)(1.5,2.7)
\psset{viewpoint=26 10 5,Decran=60}
\psSolid[object=new, linewidth=0.7\pslinewidth,
action=draw*,
sommets= 
(long chain of coordinates which I do not insert here)
faces={
(long chain of vertices which I do not insert here)
}]%
\uput[270](0,0){$n=5$}
\end{pspicture}
```

I want to color one of the faces in a light gray color. I can color a face (say the face number 2) by adding the option "fcol=2 Gray" to \psSolid. This works; however, the color is to dark for my purposes. If I understand this correctly, than the color names allowed in "fcol" are the dvips colors (Gray is one of these colors). However, within the 68 colors predefined in dvipsnames, there is no light gray color. In the pst-solides3d documentation, there is a list of colors defined in svgnames, containing the desired color "LightGray". Before that list, the following is written:

*The following colours are known by PSTricks, when the option svgnames is given. These ones are not identified by the file solides.pro: we can use them directly with the option fcol. These colours are delivered from the package xcolor.*

I want to know what I have to do so that "fcol=2 LightGray" works. Before I worried about this issue, the (beginning of the) preamble of my .tex-file looked as follows:

```
\documentclass[singlecolumn, nofootinbib, notitlepage]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{pst-poly}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
```

I tried to modify my preamble to make "fcol=2 LightGray" work, but I was not successful. For example, I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[singlecolumn, nofootinbib, notitlepage]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[svgnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{pst-poly}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
```

This does not help: I get the error message "Error: /undefined in LightGray". Giving xcolor the option "svgnames" as well does not help either: same error message. Giving the option "svgnames" to pst-solides3d produces the error "! Latex Error: Unknown option 'svgnames' for package 'pst-solides3d'."

I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are several possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\definecolor{myColA}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{myColB}{cmyk}{0.6,0.2,0.8,0.1}

\begin{document}
\psset{Decran=20,viewpoint=20 0 20 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint}

\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-3)(4,2)
\psSolid[numfaces=all,
         object=anneau,
         fillcolor=yellow,
         h=1.5,r1=4,r0=3,
         color1=myColA,
         fcol=68 (color1) 
              72 (0.7 setgray) 
              76 (\pst@usecolor{myColB})]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and for the next time: please provide *complete* examples and not only fragments!